# Получение тела запроса и обновление соответствующего поля структуры Golang

Tags: json, http, golang, curl

В рамках обучения пытаюсь реализовать небольшой REST API на Golang.

Есть следующая структура:

```golang
type Inventory struct {
    Ip     string            `json:"ip"`
    Tag    []string          `json:"tag"`
    Apps   []string          `json:"apps"`
    Active bool              `json:"active"`
    Params map[string]string `json:"params"`
}
```

Пример заполненной структуры:

```json
{
  "ip": "0.0.0.0",
  "tag": [
    "something tag"
  ],
  "apps": [
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ],
  "active": true,
  "params": {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
  }
}
```

При этом "висит" HTTP сервер и обрабатывает запросы (с ним все в порядке).

Далее, я делаю следующий запрос, например, для обновления поля "ip":

```
curl -X UPDATE http://127.0.0.1:8059/... -d '{"ip":"1.2.3.4"}'
```

Вопрос в следующем:

1. как правильно прочитать "тело" запроса (с этим проблем в принципе нет, но хотелось бы услышать другие, возможно более правильные варианты).
2. как правильно определить какое именно поле необходимо переписать.
3. и, собственно, как правильно перезаписать это поле сохранив при этом целостность структуры и остальных полей.

Особо интересна возможность перезаписи нескольких полей сразу, особенно поля "Params".

Comment: Наверное самым простым решением будет если задекларировать `Inventory` как `map` вместо `struct` тогда просто записывая `ip` из вашего примера вы будете обновлять одно поле не задевая при этом все остальные. Больше кода... провека в ручную...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось намного проще.

Добавил опцию *«omitempty»* (но как показали эксперименты, в моем случае это не обязательно).

```golang
type Inventory struct {
    Ip     string            `json:"ip,omitempty"`
    Tag    []string          `json:"tag,omitempty"`
    Apps   []string          `json:"apps,omitempty"`
    Active bool              `json:"active,omitempty"`
    Params map[string]string `json:"params,omitempty"`
}
```

Опция *«omitempty»* указывает, что поле должно быть опущено из кодировки, если поле имеет пустое значение, определенное как `false`, `0`, указатель `nil`, значение интерфейса `nil` и любой пустой *массив*, *срез*, *карта* или *строка*. Более подробно [в документации пакета json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/).

Заполненная структура (*пример*):

```golang
{
  "ip": "0.0.0.0",
  "tag": [
      "something tag"
  ],
  "apps": [
      "foo",
      "bar"
  ],
  "active": true,
  "params": {
      "key1": "val1",
      "key2": "val2"
  }
}
```

Далее, http запрос (*пример*):

```
curl -X UPDATE http://127.0.0.1:8059/... -d '{"ip":"1.2.3.4"}'
```

Читаем "тело" запроса, перекодируем байты в json и пишем в структуру:

```golang
var document Inventory

body, error := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if error != nil {
    fmt.Println(error.Error())
}
error = json.Unmarshal(body, &document)
if error != nil {
    fmt.Println(w, "can't unmarshal: ", error.Error())
}
```

При этом будут переписаны только те поля структуры, которые были указаны в запросе, в данном случае - поле "Ip". Значения других полей останутся без изменений.

Для перезаписи значений поля "Params", необходимо указывать ключи, значения которых необходимо переписать.

Answer (score 0):

На вскидку два варианта: первый используем [reflect](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) второй оч просто начинаем всё с `map`.

https://play.golang.com/p/ph9PuiEOCrU

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Inventory struct {
    Ip     string            `json:"ip"`
    Tag    []string          `json:"tag"`
    Apps   []string          `json:"apps"`
    Active bool              `json:"active"`
    Params map[string]string `json:"params"`
}

type Inventory2 map[string]interface{}

var jsonRaw = `{"ip":"0.0.0.0","tag":["something tag"],"apps":["foo","bar"],"active":true,"params":{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}} `

func main() {
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // struct
    var inv Inventory

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonRaw), &inv)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // куча проверок опущено
    // детали здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396678/678491
    reflect.ValueOf(&inv).Elem().FieldByName("Ip").SetString("1.2.3.4")

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n\n", inv.Ip)

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // map
    var inv2 Inventory2

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonRaw), &inv2)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    inv2["ip"] = "1.2.3.4"

    fmt.Println(inv2["ip"])
}
```

В обоих случаях обработчик запросов загоняет ваш UPDATE в `map[string]interface{}`.